# How can I prepend a string to the beginning of each line in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have the following bash code which loops through a text file, line by line .. im trying to prefix the work 'prefix' to each line but instead am getting this error:

```
rob@laptop:~/Desktop$ ./appendToFile.sh stusers.txt kp
stusers.txt
kp
./appendToFile.sh: line 11: /bin/sed: Argument list too long
115000_210org@house.com,passw0rd
```

This is the bash script ..

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
string=$2

echo "$file"
echo "$string"

for line in `cat $file`
do
    sed -e 's/^/prefix/' $line
    echo "$line"
done < $file
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Update:
Performing head on file dumps all the lines onto a single line of the terminal, probably related?

```
rob@laptop:~/Desktop$ head stusers.txt
rob@laptop:~/Desktop$ ouse.com,passw0rd
```

Comment: You probably have invalid line endings in the file.  Perhaps you want `dos2unix`

Comment: @WilliamPursell i tried running dos2unix against the file but did not insert the new lines for me, easiest solution was copy file contents into a new file

Comment: [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) is _deeply_ on-point. `for line in` is misleading, because it's not actually lines that are iterated over.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

a one-line awk command should do the trick also:

```
awk '{print "prefix" $0}' file
```

Answer (score 36):

Concerning your original error:

> ./appendToFile.sh: line 11: /bin/sed: Argument list too long

The problem is with this line of code:

```
sed -e 's/^/prefix/' $line
```

`$line` in this context is **file name** that *sed* is running against.  To correct your code you should fix this line as such:

```
echo $line | sed -e 's/^/prefix/'
```

(Also note that your original code should not have the `< $file` at the end.)

William Pursell addresses this issue correctly in both of his suggestions.

However, I believe you have correctly identified that there is an issue with your original text file.  `dos2unix` will not correct this issue, as it only strips the carriage returns Windows sticks on the end of lines.  (However, if you are attempting to read a Linux file in Windows, you would get a mammoth line with no returns.)

Assuming that it is not an issue with the end of line characters in your text file, William Pursell's, Andy Lester's, or nullrevolution's answers will work.

A variation on the `while read...` suggestion:

```
while read -r line; do  echo "PREFIX " $line; done < $file
```

This could be run directly from the shell (no need for a batch / script file):

```
while read -r line; do echo "kp" $line; done < stusers.txt
```

Comment: 1) turn off field splitting so you don't strip leading and trailins blanks, and 2) quote your variables for MANY reasons: `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "kp" "$line"; done < stusers.txt`. You could also argue for using print instead of echo.

Comment: Specifying `-e` doesn't seem necessary with `sed`.

Answer (score 16):

The entire loop can be replaced by a single sed command that operates on the entire file:

```
sed -e 's/^/prefix/' $file
```

Comment: Is it also possible to check wether the line is empty or not?

Comment: Do you want to leave empty lines empty?

Comment: It's so long ago... It would be nive to know both options

Comment: The simplest way is to add another sed command to replace all lines with just the prefix with blank lines:

sed -e 's/^/prefix/' -e 's/^prefix$//' $file

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert : sed -e 's/^\(.\)/prefix \1/' file

Answer (score 5):

A Perl way to do it would be:

```
perl -p -e's/^/prefix' filename
```

or

```
perl -p -e'$_ = "prefix $_"' filename
```

In either case, that reads from `filename` and prints the prefixed lines to STDOUT.

If you add a `-i` flag, then Perl will modify the file in place.  You can also specify multiple filenames and Perl will magically do all of them.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the for loop, it is more appropriate to use `while read...`:

```
while read -r line; do
do
    echo "$line" | sed -e 's/^/prefix/'
done < $file
```

But you would be much better off with the simpler:

```
sed -e 's/^/prefix/' $file
```

Comment: the first code block did not update the file with the new prefixes and the second block only updated the first line of the file

Answer (score 2):

Use sed. Just change the word `prefix`.

```
sed -e 's/^/prefix/' file.ext
```

If you want to save the output in another file

```
sed -e 's/^/prefix/' file.ext > file_new.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sed, just concatenate the strings in the echo command

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "prefix$line"
done < filename
```

Your  loop iterates over each **word** in the file:

```
for line in `cat file`; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i '1a\
Your Text' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: The question specifies "beginning _of each line_", not just beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without sed/awk and while loops:

```
xargs -n1 printf "$prefix%s\n" < "$file"
```

Comment: `xargs -n1` is _wildly_ inefficient; you're copying a whole new copy of `/usr/bin/printf` for every line of the file; and substituting the data _into the format string_ introduces its own bugs in addition.

Comment: A less incorrect way to do this (with the caveat that it requires GNU xargs) would be `xargs -d $'\n' printf '%s%s\n' "$prefix"`

Comment: ...to support BSD xargs as well, perhaps `tr '\n' '\0' <"$file" | xargs -0 printf '%s%s\n' "$prefix"`

Comment: Note that both of those have a bug insofar as they can print a line with just the prefix and nothing else when input is empty -- but then, your original answer had that bug too; it's solvable with a GNU extension, but not portably.