# How to append a string at end of a specific line in a file in bash

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to append an alias to the end of a certain line of my hosts file. For example

I have

```
192.168.1.1    www.address1.com
192.168.1.2    www.address2.com
192.168.1.3    www.address3.com
```

I want to it to look like

```
192.168.1.1    www.address1.com
192.168.1.2    www.address2.com myalias
192.168.1.3    www.address3.com
```

I want to find the line that contains 19.2.68.1.2 and append myalias at the end of it. The line is not necessarily the second line in the file like I've shown here. It could be anywhere.

Comment: The question is not precisely identical but some of the answers are.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Using `sed` and the pattern described:

```
sed '/192.168.1.2/s/$/ myalias/' file
```

---

Using `sed` and a specific line number:

```
sed '2s/$/ myalias/' file
```

Comment: `sed '2s/$/ myalias/' file > file ` make the file empty, is there any way we can  save the output in the same file ?

Comment: @Chauhan: With in-place editing: `sed -i.bak '2s/$/ myalias/' file` or just `sed '2s/$/ myalias/' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`

Comment: How about to prepend to a line?

Comment: to prepend just replace `$` to `^`  ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/13588498/2671470

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution is also possible:

```
awk '{if (/^192\.168\.1\.2 /) {$0=$0 " myalias"}; print}' hosts
```

The above reads lines from the `hosts` file one by one.  If the line has our IP address at the beginning, then `myalias` is appended to the line.  The line is then printed to `stdout`.

Note two things.  There is a space after the IP address in the `if` condition.  Otherwise, the regex could match `192.168.1.20` etc.  Also, the periods in the IP address are escaped with backslashes.  Otherwise, they could match any character.

A pithier form of the solution is:

```
awk '/^192\.168\.1\.2 /{$0=$0 " myalias"}1' hosts
```

Comment: `awk '/^192\.168\.1\.2 /{$0=$0 " myalias"}7' hosts`

Comment: How to make this change in-place? Is there a better solution than my dirty hack? `awk '{if (/^After\=/) {$0=$0 " postgresql.service"}; print}' jetty.service > jetty.service.tmp && mv -f jetty.service.tmp jetty.service`

Comment: @gouessej If your `awk` is BSD (MacOS), then your hack is the correct solution. If your `awk` is GNU (Linux, homebrew, etc), then can use the `-i inplace` option instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `awk`, since you can use strings and do not have to use regex, where dots would need to be escaped and anchors and/or word boundaries would need to be used. Also you can make sure the string matches a value in column 1.

```
awk '$1==s{$0=$0 OFS alias}1' s=192.168.1.2 alias=myalias file
```

Also when it is part of a larger script, it is nice to be able to use variable strings. With `sed` you would need shell variables and quote trickery..

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `awk`

```
awk '/search pattern/{print $0 " myalias"; next}1'  file
```

Comment: OP doesn't want the `\n` :) also this cmd will only print the matched line, which may not what OP wants

Comment: Sorry about that Kent. Was answering from phone and the way it was formatted on phone it appeared OP wanted newline. Thanks for pointing it out. `:)`

Comment: Lesson learnt. Don't answer from phone!

Comment: jaypal, you do need a "smart" phone! I guess you are using iphone right? not smart enough... :)