# How to add text at end of some specific lines

Tags: python

I have a file which contains:

```
    /home/hedgehog/image_0037.jpg
    /home/hedgehog/image_0048.jpg
    /home/hedgehog/image_0039.jpg
    /home/brain/image_0053.jpg
    /home/brain/image_0097.jpg
    /home/brain/image_0004.jpg
```

I want to add 0 at the end of the lines containing "/hedgehog/", and want to add 1 at the end of the lines containing "/brain/" like this:

```
/home/hedgehog/image_0037.jpg 0
/home/hedgehog/image_0048.jpg 0
/home/hedgehog/image_0039.jpg 0
/home/brain/image_0053.jpg 1 
/home/brain/image_0097.jpg 1
/home/brain/image_0004.jpg 1
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty straight-forward task, with or without Python. Where is your issue?

Comment: It does not seem to be very related to Ubuntu to me. Most other OSes can have files too.

Comment: I need a command which will add a label such as 0,1,2,3... at the end of the line according to there folder name.different folder images will have different labels. but same folder images will have the same label.

Comment: I am trying this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159044/how-to-append-a-string-at-end-of-a-specific-line-in-a-file-in-bash

Comment: Thank you but i am found my answer...https://superuser.com/questions/841187/append-text-at-the-end-of-a-specific-line

Answer (score 0):

```
# first read the file contents:
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()

# then iterate over each line and add 0 or 1 accordingly
modified_lines = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('/home/hedgehog/'):
        line += ' 0'
    elif line.startswith('/home/brain/'):
        line += ' 1'
    modified_lines.append(line)

# finally save your modified lines to a new file
with open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:  
    for line in modified_lines:
        fout.write('%s\n' % line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way of doing it:

```
    # new data to be written
    new_data = ""
    # open text file
    with open ("input.txt", "r+") as in_file:
      # loop each line
      for line in in_file:
        # remove newline character
        line = line.strip("\n\r")
        if "hedgehog" in line:
          line+=" 0"
        if "brain" in line:
          line+=" 1"
        # create the new version and add it to the new file data
        new_data+=line+"\n"
    # write to the file
    with open ("input.txt", "w+") as out_file:
      out_file.write(new_data)
```