# Perl Or Bash - Prefix , remove , swap text around

Tags: bash, perl

Related to a previous [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919379/perl-or-bash-script-prefix-lines-in-text-file-with-text-from-earlier-in-file/38919979#38919979). I wanted to add some prefix based on text occurring in a file.

My next piece of the jigsaw - I need to manipulate text a little and have spent a while digging around.

My file now shows: ( the lines will contact differing text - not all the same like im showing )

```
Denver.Line 1   ExtraText  I need this information
Denver.Line 2   ExtraText  I need this information
Denver.Line 3   ExtraText  I need this information
New York.Line 1   ExtraText  I need this information 
New York.Line 2   ExtraText  I need this information
```

I need

```
The place is called Denver.Line 1 and we say "I need this information"!
The place is called Denver.Line 2 and we say 'I need this information'!
The place is called Denver.Line 3 and we say 'I need this information'!
The place is called New York.Line 1 and we say 'I need this information'!
The place is called New York.Line 2 and we say 'I need this information'!
```

So.. 
I need to prefix the lines
I need to remove "   ExtraText  " and replace with "and we say'"
I need to append each line with "'!"

Thanks in advance to the gurus here.

Comment: Is the  "ExtraText" the actual string "ExtraText", or an arbitrary string?

Comment: Is the input file tab-separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `bash` version of a solution.  My results are based on your input data as given and your requested output.  The input data is in the file `input.txt` for this code.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='.' read text1 text2
do
  set -f
  textarr=($text2)
  echo "The place is called $text1.${textarr[0]} ${textarr[1]} and we say '${textarr[3]} ${textarr[4]} ${textarr[5]} ${textarr[6]}'!"
done < input.txt
```

Input data (i.e. file `input.txt`):

```
Denver.Line 1   ExtraText  I need this information
Denver.Line 2   ExtraText  I need this information
Denver.Line 3   ExtraText  I need this information
New York.Line 1   ExtraText  I need this information
New York.Line 2   ExtraText  I need this information
```

Results:

```
The place is called Denver.Line 1 and we say 'I need this information'!
The place is called Denver.Line 2 and we say 'I need this information'!
The place is called Denver.Line 3 and we say 'I need this information'!
The place is called New York.Line 1 and we say 'I need this information'!
The place is called New York.Line 2 and we say 'I need this information'!
```

Comment: Thank you - sorry for the delay - was out of the office.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input file consists of tab-separated values,

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my @fields = split /\t/;
   print("This place is called $fields[0] and we say \"$fields[2]\"!\n");
}
```

If not,

```
while (<>) {
   my ($name, $text) = /^(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(.*)/;
   print("This place is called $name and we say \"$text\"!\n");
}
```

Note that `ExtraText` can't contain spaces in this scenario.