# How to append the specific path in the given file list and update the filelist

Tags: bash, shell

Earlier I created the below question, unfortunately it has been closed.
[How to append the path in the given file list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830261/how-to-append-the-path-in-the-given-file-list)
I made a mistake in that question, Now I have corrected it in this question.
Due to that I have created a new post.

I'm looking for a bash/shell script approach.

My file list consists of different types of file names.

I want to append the path at the beginning of each line in the file list.

`file_list.txt` contents:

```
pkg/arc/PM/MW/aaa.ctf
bbb.lst
ccc.lst
pkg/arc/scr/mass/dim/config/hsc.c.in
pkg/arc/PM/MW/ddd.pkg
eee.lst
```

I want to append the specific path of each file in the file list.
Following output should be updated on the same `file_list.txt`
Example output:

```
d:est/build/rdb/pkg/arc/PM/MW/aaa.ctf
d:est/build/bbb.lst
d:est/build/ccc.lst
d:est/build/mass/dim/config/hsc.c.in
d:est/build/rdb/pkg/arc/PM/MW/ddd.pkg
d:est/build/eee.lst
```

**My Code:**
I tried the following command to modify and update the path:

```
SCRDIR="d:est/build/"
PMDIR="d:est/build/rdb/pkg/arc/PM"
sed -i -e "s|^|${SCRDIR}|" file_list.txt
sed -i "s#.*scr#$SCRDIR#g" file_list.txt
sed -i "s#.*PM#$PMDIR#g" file_list.txt
```

By using above three command I can achieve the result. But is there any other way or approach to get the same output.

Comment: You should add your code and show as what you did and what error you got. If you don't add your code, this question will be close too.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
I will add my code portion

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586349/how-can-i-prepend-a-string-to-the-beginning-of-each-line-in-a-file

Comment: @Lety the one which you mentioned is about adding some string at the beginning or middle by specifying number, which is not related to my question.

Comment: @user1934428 it’s about adding prefix. My case not only adding prefix also replacing. If you check my expected output line 4 and the input line 4.

Comment: According to which rule do you just prefix the line by `d:est/build/` or replace something? I wouldn't use `sed` here but loop over the lines and for each line decide, which transformation you want to apply. `sed` is better suitable to do the same operation to each line.

Comment: You can apply your rules in one sed command: sed -e "s|^|${SCRDIR}|;s|pkg/arc/PM|rdb/pkg/arc/PM|;s|pkg/arc/scr/||" this work because sed use pattern space where rule are applied and at the end the result is printed out. Hope this help