# BASH: add prefix to each line on curl output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to figure how to add a prefix at the beggining of each line where the lines are the output of curl:

I have the following command and output:

`curl -s https://www.url.com/ | grep -Eo '/news/[^ >]+'`

```
/news/category/title-new-bla-bla
/news/category2/title-new-bla-bla2
/news/category3/title-new-bla-bla3
/news/category4/title-new-bla-bla4
```

I would to add to my command, maybe using sed or another tool, the prefix `https://www.url.com/` to each line as follows:

```
https://www.url.com/news/category/title-new-bla-bla
https://www.url.com/news/category2/title-new-bla-bla2
https://www.url.com/news/category3/title-new-bla-bla3
https://www.url.com/news/category4/title-new-bla-bla4
```

Any help would me amazing please!

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099471/add-a-prefix-string-to-beginning-of-each-line)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prepend a string to the beginning of each line in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586349/how-can-i-prepend-a-string-to-the-beginning-of-each-line-in-a-file)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the output of `curl -s https://www.url.com/` that you want to produce your shown final expected output from so we can use that to test a solution against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```bash
  curl -s https://www.url.com/ \
| grep -Eo '/news/[^ >]+' \
| xargs -I "{}" echo "https://www.url.com{}"'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` instead of `grep`:

```bash
curl -s https://www.url.com/ | 
sed -nE 's~.*(/news/[^ >]+).*~https://www.url.com\1~p'
```

This `sed` will search for the same pattern `/news/[^ >]+` in a line and in replacement it prefixes each line with `https://www.url.com`.

Comment: This won't skip the non-matching lines.

Comment: Valid point @choroba, fixed now

Comment: Thanks a lot @choroba! amazing sed pattern by the way!. my goal is to create patterns like that

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -En '\~^/news/~s~^~https://www.url.com~p' <(curl -s https://www.url.com/)
https://www.url.com/news/category/title-new-bla-bla
https://www.url.com/news/category2/title-new-bla-bla2
https://www.url.com/news/category3/title-new-bla-bla3
https://www.url.com/news/category4/title-new-bla-bla4
```

Answer (score 0):

we have:

```
curl -s https://www.url.com | grep -Eo '/news/[^ >]+'
```

then, we can add a sed:

```
curl -s https://www.url.com | grep -Eo '/news[^ >]+' \
| sed 's|^|https://www.url.com/|'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using GNU `grep` I assume you also have GNU `awk` in which case you can use multi-char `RS` and `RT`:

```
curl -s https://www.url.com/ |
awk -v RS='/news/[^ >]+' 'RT{print "https://www.url.com/" RT}'
```